# Measuing a Product Click - Enhanced E-commerce Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, php, google-analytics, e-commerce

I want to measure Impression and Clicks of each product using Enhanced E-commerce Google Analytics. I have made two function for Impression and Clicks.

```
// function to count clicks
<script type="text/javascript">
function product_click(id,name,list){
    var script_open = '<script type="text/javascript">';
    var require = "ga('require', 'ec');";
    var product = "ga('ec:addProduct',{'id':'"+id+"','name':'"+ name+"'});";
    var send = "ga('ec:send');";
    var action = "ga('ec:setAction', 'click', {'list':'"+ list+"'}); </";
    var script_closed = 'script>';
    var clicks = script_open+require+product+send+action+script_closed;
    jQuery('#click_code').html(clicks);

    console.log(clicks);
    return clicks;
}
</script>

<div id="click_code"></div>
<div class="category_thumbArea" onClick="return product_click('abcd','pqrs','Category_Page');">
</div> // call to product_click()

// function to count impressions
function addImpression($itemCode, $itemName, $list) {
    $script_open = '<script type="text/javascript">';
    $code = "ga('require', 'ec');
             ga('ec:addImpression', {
               'id': '".$itemCode."',
               'name': '".$itemName."',
               'list': '".$list."'
             });
             ga('send', 'pageview'); ";
    $script_close = '</script>';

    return $script_open.$code.$script_close;
}

echo $imp = addImpression($itemCode,$itemName,'Category_Page'); // call to addImpression()
```

I am able to capture impressions properly but not clicks. If the argument is "Search Results" for product_click(), it will count clicks against "Search Results" but if the argument anything (e.g.: "Category_Page") other than that it can not count the clicks against it ("Category_Page") or "Search Results"

Is there anything wrong in the code or it is restricted for the words "Search Results" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I referred [Enhanced Ecommerce Product Click](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/enhanced-ecommerce#product-click) event and it looks like you haven't sent the click event to GA.

```
  // Send click with an event, then send user to product page.
  ga('send', 'event', 'UX', 'click', 'Results', {
      'hitCallback': function() {
        document.location = '/product_details?id=P12345';
      }
  });
```

Adding this in your `product_click` function just before `script_closed` string would probably trigger it.

You will need to change the `document.location` source according to your code.

Also, why append static javascript code on your page when you should directly execute it from your function? Replace all that simply with this-

```
ga('require', 'ec');
ga('ec:addProduct', {'id': id,'name': name});
ga('ec:send');
ga('ec:setAction', 'click', {'list': list});

// Send click with an event, then send user to product page.
ga('send', 'event', 'UX', 'click', 'Results', {
    'hitCallback': function() {
        document.location = '/product_details?id=P12345';
    }
});
```

Do test and let me know if it works.